# Assertion Failed in C++ questions

Tags: c++, assert

Running into an issue with some code I'm working on. This code is being run on a linux-based system and the error I receive is the following:
/root/cvswork/pci_sync_card/Code/SSBSupport/src/CRCWbHfChannel/CRCWbHfMSBSimulator.cpp:447:
virtual void CCRCWbHfMSBSimulator::Process(): Assertion 'pcBasebandOutput' failed.

I've tried stepping through this code to figure out why this is failing and I can't seem to figure it out. Unfortunately I have too many files to really share the code on here (stepping through the pcBasebandOutput assignment takes quite some time). I understand this is a more complex issue than can really be asked about. My primary questions are these:

1. Is my assert(pcBasebandOutput); line of code necessary? I only ask because when running this code on Visual Studio, the results from my program were desirable.
2. When it is evaluating my pcBasebandOutput variable, why would it evaluate it as false? Is this saying that no value is actually assigned to pcBasebandOutput? Or that a value may be assigned to it, but it is not of the right type (pointer to a struct of two variables, both of which are doubles)?

Thanks!

Comment: If someone can explain why I received a downvote as well, that'd be appreciated. Second time it's happened to me on this site with no explanation. If you don't like my question, please tell me what I did wrong so I don't do it again.

Comment: I think most people who can help you would rather have some code than personal background.

Comment: Yeah, really, there's just way too much here that indicates a more complex problem, without giving enough details to actually respond to them. If you **only** want help with those two questions, then you should only post those two questions. If you want help on the whole issue, you need to post a lot more information. Which, of course, might not get much attention because there's so much involved. You may need to do some more work to break this down into a concise example or question that allows people to actually answer it.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. I'll remember that for the future, as well as I'll edit this question.

Comment: Compilers from different vendors (VS, g++, ... )will handle undefined behaviours ( uninitialize variables, ... ) in different manners, sometimes they will generate asserts, sometimes they will just luckily continue executation as if nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assert` checks a logical condition. Assertation fails if the condition is `false`. So writing `assert(cond)` is logically the same as writing:

```
if (!cond)
{
    assert(false);
}
```

I don't suggest you to remove `assert` from the code, because it is a guard telling you that something went not the way it's intended to go. And it's not a god idea just to ignore that, because it may shoot you in a leg later

Comment: Thank you @Andrew. I had a feeling a shouldn't remove it for that exact reason even though the program has the proper output on Visual Studio.

As far as the logical condition goes, I understand what you are saying, but what I'm still a little unclear about (which maybe I don't understand what you are saying if I am) is what it's actually logically comparing pcBasebandOutput to. Is it simply checking to see if it exists? Or if it's of the proper data type? I apologize if this seems like a dumb question.

Comment: @TZPike05: I think assertation went ok when running the program in Visual Studio

Comment: Is the line just `assert(pcBasebandOutput);`? That's probably a null pointer check, rather than looking at anything inside `pcBasebandOutput`.

Comment: @BoBTFish: if pcBasebandOutput is a pointer - yes. That checks it's not nullptr

Comment: Thank you both! That helps me understand so much now. Now I have an idea of what I'm looking for. I'm guessing there is something wrong with my return value for the function I'm using to assign a value to pcBasebandOutput.

Answer (score 1):

1. Only you can know that
2. What is the type of pcBasebandOutput ? Maybe it is not properly initialized?

assert primary purpose is to allow your IDE to enter debuging session in the place where assert has hit. From there you can read all variables and see callstack/threads. Other solution (than using debugger) is to add lots of logging, which in threaded environments can cause problems on its own (logging is quite slow).

Comment: pcBasebandOutput is a pointer to a struct titled COMPLEX that has two variables in it, both of which are doubles. I suppose the initialization could be wrong, but I would assume it would have failed on Visual Studio as well when I ran it there.